# The argument type 'FirebaseAuthProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AuthService'

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

```
Hello please help me am getting stack when creating an Auth Service with Flutter. and am  getting this error message
```

'The argument type 'FirebaseAuthProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AuthService'

```
    import 'package:mynotes/service/auth_provider.dart';
    import 'package:mynotes/service/auth_user.dart';
    import 'package:mynotes/service/firebase_auth_provider.dart';
    
    class AuthService implements AuthProvider {
      final AuthService provider;
      const AuthService(this.provider);
      factory AuthService.firebase() => AuthService(FirebaseAuthProvider());
    
      // implement createUser
      @override
      Future<AuthUser> createUser({
        required String email,
        required String password,
      }) =>
          provider.createUser(
            email: email,
            password: password,
          );
    
      //implement currentUser
      @override
      AuthUser? get currentUser => provider.currentUser;
    
      //  implement login
      @override
      Future<AuthUser> login({
        required String email,
        required String password,
      }) =>
          provider.login(
            email: email,
            password: password,
          );
    
      // implement logout
      @override
      Future<void> logout() => provider.logout();
    
    // implement sendEmailVerification
      @override
      Future<void> sendEmailVerification() => provider.sendEmailVerification();
    
      @override
      Future<void> initialized() => provider.initialized();
    }
```

I have created an AuthService.dart page using flutter but when I use factory I get this error bellow
The argument type 'FirebaseAuthProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AuthService'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```dart
final AuthService provider;
```

to this:

```dart
final AuthProvider provider;
```

Please also see the GitHub repository for the Free Flutter Course to double check you implementation: https://github.com/vandadnp/mynotes-course

This specific file can be found here: https://github.com/vandadnp/mynotes-course/blob/8f021cbd58d4a4bb4d962ea2b085242b68bba989/lib/services/auth/auth_service.dart

Comment: Hi Vandad. I'm been following your flutter tutorials for some time now. Thank you for your hard work. Concerning this same issue, at line 9 in this file https://github.com/vandadnp/mynotes-course/blob/8f021cbd58d4a4bb4d962ea2b085242b68bba989/lib/services/auth/auth_service.dart I get `The argument type 'FirebaseAuthProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AuthProvider'.` I try using a cast as recommended by the error but it doesn't work. Please how do I fix this

Answer (score 0):

bro
I was getting the same error till I added this to the code and it worked fine.

factory AuthService.firebase() => AuthService (FirebaseAuthProvider as AuthProvider);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).